# Sencha Touch Production Build

Tags: javascript, sencha-charts, sencha-touch-2.2

Trying to create a production build for my Sencha Touch Charts App.

Sencha Touch 2.3.1
Sencha Charts 1.0.1
Sencha Cmd 4.0.2.67

The build runs ok, without errors. However, when I try to run the new production build, I get an error that I cannot properly identify, due to all the code being minified.

So, I created a test build, using `Sencha app build -e testing -d build`

Again, the build was performed ok with no errors.

When I try to run my app, I get an error which looks like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'registerType' of undefined app.js:81009
>   (anonymous function) app.js:81009
>   process app.js:6732
>   (anonymous function) app.js:6744
>   Ext.apply.onBeforeCreated app.js:5182
>   process app.js:5248
>   process app.js:5254
>   process app.js:5254
>   process app.js:5254
>   process app.js:5254
>   Ext.apply.process app.js:5258
>   Ext.Class.ExtClass app.js:5169
>   Ext.ClassManager.create app.js:6690
>   Ext.apply.define app.js:7385
>   (anonymous function)  app.js:80773

Line 80773 of app.js is `Ext.define('Ext.chart.interactions.ItemCompare', {`

Line 81009 of app.js is
`Ext.chart.interactions.Manager.registerType('itemcompare',Ext.chart.interactions.ItemCompare);`

That file also exists and is required in app.js

That class definitely exists and `'Ext.chart.interactions.ItemCompare'` is in app.js

Comment: What is the code around line 81009?

Comment: @vadchen have added that to the question. Thanks.

Comment: In the end I gave up on SenchaChart and used Highcharts instead